# How to seal outside electrical box against vinyl siding?

Tags: electrical

A small amount of water enters our basement periodically in a place that looks directly under this outlet.  I suspect that gap is where water is finding a very easy way into the house.

Is this a reasonable theory?  Next, how do I better seal this?  I am skeptical the gap as-is can be reasonably sealed because it is so wide.  I am thinking of cutting the left-side of this trim so the faceplate sits more flush with the siding, and the using a bead of caulk around the top and sides.

Are there other approaches I should consider?

[image]

Comment: Normally that sort of vinyl siding outlet trim has a larger flange behind the siding where it actually seals. The forward flange is spaced out to permit it to be installed anywhere on the "clapboard shape" of the vinyl siding. The two flanges make a **U** shape, so despite the large visible space, the large visible space is not likely to leak, and there isn't any way to "push" that front flange back tighter. This outlet might well be the cause of your leak, but probably not in the way I think you think it is.

Comment: @Ecnerwal -- I'm not sure what you are suggesting.  If I pull the siding and can confirm there's an inner flange there, is there another place I should be checking for the leak?

Comment: The inner flange should keep water that makes it behind the siding from making it behind the sheathing and into the wall. However, the best bet is to do what you can to keep the water from getting behind the siding in the first place. The water that's making it through this gap can run down the wall, puddle and cause rot down below.

Answer (score 4):

I would agree, cutting the left edge of the trim plate so it can sit more flush against the siding seems to be the way to go. Then caulk the top and down both sides of the trim ring. Leave the bottom open so any moisture that does get past the caulk has an easy way out instead of getting trapped against the sheathing.

Comment: I would agree especially with the calking. Many outside devices I have been called to replace over the years are full of water.